# React setState doesn't work with array.prototype.splice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was following one react tutorial from [here](http://tylermcginnis.com/reactjs-tutorial-a-comprehensive-guide-to-building-apps-with-react/) , and tried to add delete button to delete a name on the list. However, if I set the `friends:this.state.friends.splice(findIndex,1)` within the setState method, the delete won't work properly,but it will work if I set the `this.state.friends.splice(findIndex,1)` outside of the setState method, can somebody please explain why that is? Thanks  (here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnvh973y/1/)).
(edit: this is the jsx from the link )

```
var HelloHandler = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return{
            name: 'Tyler McGinnis',
            friends: ['Jake Lingwall', 'Murphy Randall', 'Merrick Christensen']
        }
    },
    addFriend: function(friend){
        this.setState({
            friends: this.state.friends.concat([friend])
        })
    },
    deleteFriend: function(name){
        findIndex=this.state.friends.indexOf(name);
        this.state.friends.splice(findIndex,1)//
        this.setState({
            friends: this.state.friends 
            //delete won't work properly if change to friends:this.state.friends.splice(findIndex,1)
        })
    },
    render: function(){
      return (
        <div>
            <div>
                Hello{this.state.name} 
            </div>
            <div>
                <PrintFriends friendList={this.state.friends} deleteFriend={this.deleteFriend}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <AddFriend addFriend={this.addFriend} />
            </div>
       </div>
      )
    }
});


var AddFriend=React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            inputName:''
         }
    },
    setFriendNameToState: function(evt){
        this.setState({
            inputName: evt.target.value
        })
    },
    updateFriendNameToList: function(){
        this.props.addFriend(this.state.inputName);
        this.setState({
            inputName: ''
        })
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <input type='text' onChange={this.setFriendNameToState} />
                <button onClick={this.updateFriendNameToList}>update list</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

 PrintFriends=React.createClass({
     deleteName: function(people){
        this.props.deleteFriend(people.name);
     },
     render: function(){
                var self=this;
                nameList=this.props.friendList.map(function(name){
                                return(
                                    <li key={name}>
                                         {name} <button onClick={this.deleteName.bind(null,{name})}>delete</button>
                                    </li>
                                )
                            }.bind(self));
                return(
                     <div>
                        <h3> Friends </h3>
                        <ul>
                            {nameList}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                )
            }
})


React.render(<HelloHandler />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Please include the actual code you are talking about in the question, not only in the link. Link-only questions are likely to be deleted.

Comment: I thought it will be easier for people if i provide the jsfiddle

Comment: @seanh http://i.imgur.com/QOoS04N.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splice` modifies the array directly and returns the spliced items. So if you set `friends` to `this.state.friends.splice(findIndex,1)`, you'll set it to the "deleted" item(s). Which I'm guessing is not at all what you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

But, you know, all you're saying is "the delete won't work properly", so you haven't really stated what's happening or what you want to happen...

Answer (score 3):

It is a very interesting question that needs to refer back to the very basic of State Rendering.
React only re-renders if the state is changed.

"Changed" here means that the state points to another object. If the state changes its value, but still points to the same object, then re-render will not happen.

More specifically:

```
friends = ['Amy', 'Beatrix', 'Cedric']
friends.splice(0,1) // friends === ['Beatrix', 'Cedric'], however, it still points to the same object.
```

To make it works, you should use filter instead:

```
// filter return a new object
this.setState({
 friends: friends.filter((value, index) => index!==findIndex)
})
```

Another way, if you array is simple enough

```
// JSON.parse return a new object  
this.setState({
 friends: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.friends)) 
})
```